# Using dependency injection with Apache Commons IO

Tags: java, dependency-injection, io

I have a class 'a' that uses the FileUtils class of Apache Commons IO to copy a directory.

Because I have to write a unit test for class 'a', I need to be able to inject all dependencies to mock them in the test.

But how to inject the FileUtils class? There is no interface and all methods are abstract.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All methods of the utility classes are static. You can't mock them (well, you can, with bytecode manipulation, but it's ugly). The proper way to handle that is to provide an abstraction over these utilities. For example implement a `FileService`, which you declare as a bean, and inject it. Then you can mock *its* methods.

Comment: @bbaja42 true, through bytecode manipulation or replacing the class in the classloader. But that's ugly at least :) I added the clarification to my answer

Comment: I agree that it is ugly, but it's also quite useful. But in this case, I prefer your solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own implementation of FileUtils by extending it OR use a mocking library like [jMockit](http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/) or [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/).

Comment: can you mock static methods with that?

Answer (score 1):

You can always wrap it in a file handling layer and create a stub implementation for your unit tests.